# Actual/expect funs in shared throw NoSuchMethodError in Kotlin Multiplatform

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-multiplatform, compose-desktop

I am developing a dummy weather app with the help of Kotlin Multiplatform. I am using Decompose and MVIKotlin to try and share all the business logic except the native uis, SwiftUI for IOS and Compose for Desktop and Android.

I am trying to have a expect composable (for dark theme and for loading of images)

```
// In common main
@Composable
expect fun isDarkMode() : Boolean

@Composable
expect fun loadWeatherIcon(id : Int) : Painter


// In android main 
@Composable
actual fun isDarkMode() : Boolean {
    return androidx.compose.foundation.isSystemInDarkTheme()
}

@Composable
actual fun loadWeatherIcon(id : Int) : Painter {
    return painterResource(id)
}

//In Desktop main
@Composable
actual fun isDarkMode() : Boolean {
    return false //isSystemInDarkTheme()
}
@Composable
actual fun loadWeatherIcon(id : Int) : Painter {
    return loadWeatherIcon(id)
}
```

Meaning they are all implemented and there, but for some reason the crash is happening with NoSuchMethodError. I found some similar issues but they all had suspend funs and default parameters. Meanwhile my approach should work like in the [jetpack todo compose sample](https://github.com/JetBrains/compose-jb/tree/master/examples/todoapp/common/compose-ui), here's my project (if you want to test what's happening, you can just clone it and run it, it should crash immediatelly)

https://github.com/Nikola-Milovic/KotlinMultiplaftorm-WeatherApp

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.nikolam.kmm_weather.androidApp, PID: 17270
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method isDarkMode(Landroidx/compose/runtime/Composer;I)Z in class Lcom/nikolam/kmm_weather/ui/UtilsKt; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.nikolam.kmm_weather.ui.UtilsKt' appears in /data/data/com.nikolam.kmm_weather.androidApp/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes4.dex)
        at com.nikolam.kmm_weather.ui.WeatherMainContentKt$WeatherMainContent$2.invoke(WeatherMainContent.kt:45)
        at com.nikolam.kmm_weather.ui.WeatherMainContentKt$WeatherMainContent$2.invoke(WeatherMainContent.kt:38)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:109)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:193)
        at com.nikolam.kmm_weather.ui.WeatherMainContentKt.WeatherMainContent(WeatherMainContent.kt:38)
        at com.nikolam.kmm_weather.ui.ComposableSingletons$WeatherRootContentKt$lambda-1$1.invoke(WeatherRootContent.kt:14)
        at com.nikolam.kmm_weather.ui.ComposableSingletons$WeatherRootContentKt$lambda-1$1.invoke(WeatherRootContent.kt:12)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:118)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
        at com.arkivanov.decompose.extensions.compose.jetbrains.ChildrenKt$Children$1$1.invoke(Children.kt:30)
        at com.arkivanov.decompose.extensions.compose.jetbrains.ChildrenKt$Children$1$1.invoke(Children.kt:29)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:109)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:193)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.saveable.SaveableStateHolderImpl.SaveableStateProvider(SaveableStateHolder.kt:84)
        at com.arkivanov.decompose.extensions.compose.jetbrains.ChildrenKt$Children$1.invoke(Children.kt:29)
        at com.arkivanov.decompose.extensions.compose.jetbrains.ChildrenKt$Children$1.invoke(Children.kt:28)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:118)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
        at com.arkivanov.decompose.extensions.compose.jetbrains.animation.page.PageAnimationKt$PageAnimationFrame$1$1$1.invoke(PageAnimation.kt:143)
        at com.arkivanov.decompose.extensions.compose.jetbrains.animation.page.PageAnimationKt$PageAnimationFrame$1$1$1.invoke(PageAnimation.kt:141)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:118)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
        at com.arkivanov.decompose.extensions.compose.jetbrains.animation.child.CrossfadeScaleKt$crossfadeScale$1.invoke(CrossfadeScale.kt:22)
        at com.arkivanov.decompose.extensions.compose.jetbrains.animation.child.CrossfadeScaleKt$crossfadeScale$1.invoke(CrossfadeScale.kt:21)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:254)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
        at com.arkivanov.decompose.extensions.compose.jetbrains.animation.page.PageAnimationKt$PageAnimationFrame$1.invoke(PageAnimation.kt:141)
        at com.arkivanov.decompose.extensions.compose.jetbrains.animation.page.PageAnimationKt$PageAnimationFrame$1.invoke(PageAnimation.kt:132)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:118)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
        at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.BoxWithConstraintsKt$BoxWithConstraints$1$1$measurables$1.invoke(BoxWithConstraints.kt:61)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.BoxWithConstraintsKt$BoxWithConstraints$1$1$measurables$1.invoke(BoxWithConstraints.kt:61)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:109)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.SubcomposeLayoutState$subcompose$2$1.invoke(SubcomposeLayout.kt:167)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.SubcomposeLayoutState$subcompose$2$1.invoke(SubcomposeLayout.kt:167)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:109)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerKt.invokeComposable(Composer.kt:3235)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.doCompose(Composer.kt:2514)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.composeContent$runtime_debug(Composer.kt:2478)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.composeContent(Composition.kt:453)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer.composeInitial$runtime_debug(Recomposer.kt:702)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl$CompositionContextImpl.composeInitial$runtime_debug(Composer.kt:2914)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.setContent(Composition.kt:409)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.SubcomposeLayoutState.subcomposeInto(SubcomposeLayout.kt:184)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.SubcomposeLayoutState.access$subcomposeInto(SubcomposeLayout.kt:100)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.SubcomposeLayoutState$subcompose$2.invoke(SubcomposeLayout.kt:160)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.SubcomposeLayoutState$subcompose$2.invoke(SubcomposeLayout.kt:158)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver.withNoObservations(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:137)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.withNoSnapshotReadObservation$ui_debug(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:49)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.withNoSnapshotReadObservation$ui_debug(LayoutNode.kt:1054)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.SubcomposeLayoutState.subcompose(SubcomposeLayout.kt:158)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.SubcomposeLayoutState.subcompose(SubcomposeLayout.kt:152)
        at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.BoxWithConstraintsKt$BoxWithConstraints$1$1.invoke-0kLqBqw(BoxWithConstraints.kt:61)
        at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.BoxWithConstraintsKt$BoxWithConstraints$1$1.invoke(BoxWithConstraints.kt:59)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.SubcomposeLayoutState$createMeasurePolicy$1.measure-3p2s80s(SubcomposeLayout.kt:212)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.InnerPlaceable.measure-BRTryo0(InnerPlaceable.kt:45)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable$remeasure$2.invoke(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:95)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable$remeasure$2.invoke(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:94)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver.observeReads(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:121)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeReads$ui_debug(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:75)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeMeasureSnapshotReads$ui_debug(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:63)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable.remeasure-BRTryo0(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:94)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable.measure-BRTryo0(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:68)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.measure-BRTryo0(LayoutNode.kt:1172)
        at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.BoxKt$boxMeasurePolicy$1.measure-3p2s80s(Box.kt:111)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.InnerPlaceable.measure-BRTryo0(InnerPlaceable.kt:45)
        at androidx.compose.ui.graphics.SimpleGraphicsLayerModifier.measure-3p2s80s(GraphicsLayerModifier.kt:213)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.ModifiedLayoutNode.measure-BRTryo0(ModifiedLayoutNode.kt:37)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.measure-BRTryo0(DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.kt:108)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at androidx.compose.ui.graphics.SimpleGraphicsLayerModifier.measure-3p2s80s(GraphicsLayerModifier.kt:213)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.ModifiedLayoutNode.measure-BRTryo0(ModifiedLayoutNode.kt:37)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable$remeasure$2.invoke(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:95)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable$remeasure$2.invoke(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:94)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver.observeReads(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:121)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeReads$ui_debug(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:75)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeMeasureSnapshotReads$ui_debug(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:63)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable.remeasure-BRTryo0(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:94)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable.measure-BRTryo0(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:68)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.measure-BRTryo0(LayoutNode.kt:1172)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.RootMeasurePolicy.measure-3p2s80s(RootMeasurePolicy.kt:38)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.InnerPlaceable.measure-BRTryo0(InnerPlaceable.kt:45)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.measure-BRTryo0(DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.kt:108)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.measure-BRTryo0(DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.kt:108)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.measure-BRTryo0(DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.kt:108)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.measure-BRTryo0(DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.kt:108)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable$remeasure$2.invoke(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:95)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable$remeasure$2.invoke(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:94)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.Snapshot$Companion.observe(Snapshot.kt:1787)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver.observeReads(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:116)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeReads$ui_debug(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:75)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeMeasureSnapshotReads$ui_debug(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:63)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable.remeasure-BRTryo0(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:94)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.remeasure-BRTryo0$ui_debug(LayoutNode.kt:1179)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.doRemeasure-0kLqBqw(MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.kt:170)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.access$doRemeasure-0kLqBqw(MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.kt:39)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.measureAndLayout(MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.kt:212)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.onMeasure(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:543)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25466)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView.onMeasure(ComposeView.android.kt:249)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25466)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6957)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:145)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25466)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6957)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1552)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:842)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:721)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25466)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6957)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25466)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6957)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1552)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:842)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:721)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25466)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6957)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:747)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25466)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:3397)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:2228)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2486)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1952)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:8171)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:972)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:796)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:731)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:957)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 17270 SIG:
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue where a `@Composable` annotated expected function was not visible at runtime in a different Gradle module. Hence the `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError` exception. The solution was to make the expected function internal and have a public wrapper function delegate to that internal function.

**Crashes:**

```kotlin
@Composable
expect fun Image() { ... }
```

**Does not crash:**

```kotlin
@Composable
internal expect fun InternalImage() { ... }

@Composable
fun Image() {
    InternalImage()
}
```